# Kendo-UI Scheduler how set days to run 6am to 6am

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I want to display my schedule events in day/week/month views where the day starts at 6am and ends at 6am the next day.

Is this possible with the kendo-ui Scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

Not without creating custom views. Kendo documentation states the limitations:

> The built-in views of the widget are designed to render a time-frame that ends on the day it starts. If you want to render views which start on one day and end on another, build a custom view.
>   http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/scheduler/overview#known-limitations

I'll take a swing at the Dojo example, see if I can help you out.

--edit--
Bit hacky, hope it helps:
http://dojo.telerik.com/ILaMe/4
Had to copy the whole _forTimeRange function because I couldn't extend it any other way.